# Help me clean up this crazy lambda with the out keyword

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, refactoring

My code looks ugly, and I know there's got to be a better way of doing what I'm doing:

```
private delegate string doStuff(
    PasswordEncrypter encrypter, RSAPublicKey publicKey,
    string privateKey, out string salt
);

private bool tryEncryptPassword(
    doStuff encryptPassword,
    out string errorMessage
)
{
    ...get some variables...
    string encryptedPassword = encryptPassword(encrypter, publicKey,
        privateKey, out salt);
    ...
}
```

This stuff so far doesn't bother me.  It's how I'm calling `tryEncryptPassword` that looks so ugly, and has duplication because I call it from two methods:

```
public bool method1(out string errorMessage)
{
    string rawPassword = "foo";
    return tryEncryptPassword(
        (PasswordEncrypter encrypter, RSAPublicKey publicKey,
            string privateKey, out string salt) =>
            encrypter.EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff( // Overload 1
                rawPassword, publicKey, privateKey, out salt
            ),
        out errorMessage
    );
}

public bool method2(SecureString unencryptedPassword,
    out string errorMessage)
{
    return tryEncryptPassword(
       (PasswordEncrypter encrypter, RSAPublicKey publicKey,
           string privateKey, out string salt) =>
           encrypter.EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff( // Overload 2
               unencryptedPassword, publicKey, privateKey, out salt
           ),
       out errorMessage
   );
}
```

Two parts to the ugliness:

- I have to explicitly list all the parameter types in the lambda expression because of the single `out` parameter.
- The two overloads of `EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff` take all the same parameters except for the first parameter, which can either be a `string` or a `SecureString`.  So `method1` and `method2` are pretty much identical, they just call different overloads of `EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff`.

Any suggestions?

**Edit (solution):** I ended up using Jeff's suggestion and altering the overloads of `EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff` to return an instance of `EncryptionResult`.  Then I didn't need an explicitly defined `delegate`, and I used the following code:

```
private bool tryEncryptPassword(KeysAndEncrypter keys,
    Func<EncryptionResult> encryptPassword,
    out string errorMessage
) { ... }

private class KeysAndEncrypter
{
    public RSAPublicKey PublicKey { get; set; }
    public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
    public PasswordEncrypter Encrypter { get; set; }
}
```

And here was the contents of `method1`, with `method2` being very similar:

```
string rawPassword = "foo";
KeysAndEncrypter keys = getEncryptionKeys();
return tryEncryptPassword(keys, () =>
    keys.Encrypter.EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff(
        rawPassword, keys.PublicKey, keys.PrivateKey
    ),
    out errorMessage
);
```

Comment: Do both overloads of EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff have a similar functionality? And do you use the bool return value of method1 and method2?

Comment: @Ilya:  yes, both `EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff` overloads do the same thing; in fact they just call two different overloads of an `Encrypt` method, as well as some other stuff.  The `bool` return from `method1` and `method2` is used by the callers, so it's necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could introduce a new type to represent the delegate's return value:

```
 public class EncryptionResult {
     public string EncryptedValue { get; set; }
     public string Salt { get; set; }
 }
```

... and change the delegate to something like this:

```
 private delegate EncryptionResult doStuff(
     PasswordEncrypter encrypter, 
     RSAPublicKey publicKey,
     string privateKey);
```

Comment: This works and definitely makes calling `tryEncryptPassword` cleaner, but I have to do more repetitive stuff in the lambdas.  I'll update my question so my code shows your modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with the crazy lambda at all?

```
public bool Method1(out string errorMessage)
{
    return TryEncryptPassword("foo", out errorMessage);
}

public bool Method2(SecureString password, out string errorMessage)
{
    return TryEncryptPassword(password, out errorMessage);
}

private bool TryEncryptPassword(string password, out string errorMessage)
{
    GetSomeVariables();
    string encryptedPassword = encrypter.EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff(
           password, publicKey, privateKey, out salt);
    DoMoreStuff();
    // ...
}

private bool TryEncryptPassword(SecureString password, out string errorMessage)
{
    GetSomeVariables();
    string encryptedPassword = encrypter.EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff(
           password, publicKey, privateKey, out salt);
    DoMoreStuff();
    // ...
}

private void GetSomeVariables() { /* ...get some variables... */ }

private void DoMoreStuff() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: My `...`'s were misleading:  there's a lot of code above and below the call to `EncryptPasswordAndDoStuff`.  However, maybe I should focus on refactoring that to make it shorter and simpler, then do what you suggest.

Comment: @Sarah: You could presumably take the shared code out into separate private methods and call them from both of the `TryEncryptPassword` overloads. Those overloads would then be practically empty.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's suggestion is reasonable. You could just use a `Tuple<string, string>` too though if you don't want to define a new type each time you need an out parameter.

Another suggestion would be to pass in another delegate to retrieve the error rather then using an out param.

```
private bool tryEncryptPassword(
     doStuff encryptPassword,
     Action<string> setError
)

public bool method1(Action<string> setError) {
    ...
    tryEncryptPassword(..., ..., ..., setError);
}
```

Before calling method1, you can assign your setError to a local variable.

```
string error;
Action<string> setError = str => error = str;
method1(setError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want to create a custom type, you could return a tuple here.

```
private delegate Tuple<string, string> doStuff(
   PasswordEncrypter encrypter, 
   RSAPublicKey publicKey,
   string privateKey);
```

within doStuff, just create and return a tuple:

```
Tuple<string, string> result = new Tuple<string, string>(EncryptedValue, Salt);
return result;
```